# Save File With Shell Script Content

Tags: linux, bash

`$net_script` is variable and stored text (script content). I need to create `run.sh` with `$net_script` content.

`$net_script`:

```
echo "Start..."
cat <<EOF > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$1
DEVICE=$1
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=$2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=$3
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
EOF
```

But it's not stored correctly. I tried `echo` but that didn't work.

```
cat <<'EOF' >> run.sh $net_script EOF
```

Comment: Are you trying to create this script?

Comment: @Paula Livingstone my script source stored on varieble($net_script) and i try to create .sh file with cat

Comment: So you have a file called $net_script as shown above and youre trying to create a file called run.sh which has the same content??

Comment: $net_script is variable and stored text (script content),  need to create run.sh with $net_script content

Comment: Where is powershell used in any of this?  `$variable | Out-File -FilePath $Path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
echo "${net_script}" > run.sh
```

Comment: thanks that's work but every $ char is removed on run.sh